# how to put thumbnail scroll to site

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

how can I incorporate thumbnail scroll if my site's theme (timber) uses csswizardry?

Here's a snippet of my product page code:

```
    {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
      <ul class="product-photo-thumbs grid-uniform mThumbnailScroller" data-mts-axis="x" id="productThumbs">

        {% for image in product.images %}
          <li class="grid-item medium-down--one-quarter large--one-quarter">
            <a href="{{ image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" class="product-photo-thumb">
              <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}

      </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

Here's for the css part:

```css
.product-photo-container {
  margin-bottom: $gutter;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product-photo-container,
.product-photo-thumbs {
  a, img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: $gutter;
  }
}

#productThumbs{
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

@include at-query($min, $large) {
  // Image zoom
  .image-zoom {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: move;
  }
}
```

All of my thumbnails are currently being displayed. What should I do to make it so that only 1 row will show and the rest will be scrolled? Here's a link to my site: http://www.hobime.com/collections/arrives-in-1-week/products/spider-man-carnage-fine-art-statue-1-6-scaled-figure?variant=7423987201

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to give the `<li>`s `display:inline-block` combined with setting `overflow:auto`, `white-space:nowrap`, and a width on the parent list:

HTML:

```
<ul class="product-photo-thumbs">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.product-photo-thumbs {
  margin:1em;
  font-family:arial, sans-serif; 
  width:400px;
  overflow:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;

  li {
    font-size:2em;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:1em;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border:2px solid #777;
  }
}
```

Example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/zesposi/pen/dYJzXq

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work :( It still shows the whole thumbnail without the scroll.. I'm guessing the csswizardry is affecting this display..